# How does reddit create the top header without any margins?

Tags: html, css

I was looking through the code using the chrome developer tool and I tried to emulate it on my website but it doesn't work the same way.

Apparently by setting the margin: 0;, the margins are erased but don't the margins need to technically be negative for there to be no space?

I am not seeing in the css formatting how the margins are completely gone.

Any ideas?

my css:

```
.header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

my html:

```
<div class = "header">
    <strong>Categories:</strong>
    <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
    <a href = ".?category_id=<?php echo $category['categoryID'];?>"><?php echo $category['categoryName'];?></a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>        
</div>
```

Comment: Create a code example, showing what you've tried.

Comment: Do they have a reset.css? http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting margins to zero should be sufficient to make it line up with whatever's containing it—but what's containing it might be providing its own spacing. I'm guessing that while you *have* removed the margin on the header, you haven't removed any padding from the body. Try adding this rule:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you aren't reseting you browser's default CSS. Try adding:

```
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

and see if that will get rid of your spacing issue. Some people don't like using this method to reset padding and margins since it applies this rule to everything. But as a quick test to determine if this is your issue this code will be perfect.

If this does fix you're problem, try looking around for a good CSS reset and add it to your site.